# Парсинг JSON, возвращаемый php в java android

Tags: php, java, android, json

Привет, у меня есть php, который мне json'ом возвращает несколько значений:

- day
- class
- letter
- lesson
- task

Он их берёт из таблицы SQL и возвращает вроде как массивом.

Вот код php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
   $result = $conn->query($sql); 

   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   { 
       $day["day:"] = ($row['day']);
       $class["class:"] = ($row['class']);
       $letter["letter:"] = ($row['letter']);
       $lesson["lesson:"] = ($row['lesson']);
       $task["task:"] = ($row['task']);

       echo json_encode($day);
       echo json_encode($class);
       echo json_encode($letter);
       echo json_encode($lesson);
       echo json_encode($task);
   }
```

Так вот пытаюсь я это в java коде принять, и вроде как принимаю, и всё бы было ничего, но тут сталкиваюсь с проблемой..

Мне необходимо запихнуть данные в `ListView`..

Вот такую штуку скрипт мне даёт:

```
{"day:":"Четверг"}{"class:":"3 класс"}{"letter:":"А"}{"lesson:":"География"}{"task:":"Задание 1"}
```

Я ее в приложении принял в строку и передал в JSONObject и пытаюсь передать в ListView следующим кодом:

```
public void JSONURL(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println(json);
            JSONObject uDay = json.getJSONObject("day");
            JSONObject uClass = json.getJSONObject("class");
            JSONObject uLetter = json.getJSONObject("letter");
            JSONObject uLesson = json.getJSONObject("lesson");
            JSONObject uTask = json.getJSONObject("task");

            for (int i = 0; i < uLesson.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> hm;
                hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                hm.put(DAY, uDay.getString("day").toString());
                hm.put(CLASS, uClass.getString("class").toString());
                hm.put(LETTER, uLetter.getString("letter").toString());
                hm.put(LESSON, uLesson.getString("lesson").toString());
                hm.put(TASK, uTask.getString("task").toString());
                myBooks.add(hm);

                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(showHomework.this, myBooks, R.layout.list,
                        new String[] { TASK, CLASS, LETTER, LESSON, DAY}, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4, R.id.text5  });

                //выводим в листвью
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Вооот... А терминал Android Studio выдаёт ошибку:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for day.

Как я понял моё код не может найти соответственное значение **day** в json'е..

Ребят, прошу не ругаться, я в этой теме новичок.. Помогите чем можете..

Comment: ваша строка не является валидным JSON ом, соответственно, распарсить ее вы не сможете.

Comment: Java не знаю толком, но из логики, ключ в json у вас, например, `day:`', а достать пытаетесь `day` (без двоеточия). Вы или из самого массива, в php, уберите двоеточия из ключей, или доставайте правильно

Comment: Да и как верно написали выше, вы не верно формируете json

Answer (score 2):

Формируем массив, в php, и конвертируем в json строку

```
$data=[
    'day'=>$row['day'],
    'class'=>$row['class'],
    'letter'=>$row['letter'],
    'lesson'=>$row['lesson'],
    'task'=>$row['task']
];

echo json_decode($data);
```

Пример Java:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(response);
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
System.out.println(jsonObj.get("day"));
```

С java не знаком, по этому - [Источник](http://goloburdin.blogspot.com/2011/03/json-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Эксепшен вы получаете потому что вы пытаетесь взять значение по неправильному ключу. Сервер вам возвращает значение дня по ключу "day:", а вы парсите по ключу "day". Просто добавьте двоеточие, и все заработает.(то же самое в остальных полях)